# Programly add empty section to iOS MachO file?

Tags: ios, c, gcc, linker, mach-o

It seems that adding `-Wl,-sectcreate,__RESTRICT,__restrict,/dev/null` in `Other Linker Flags` will add an empty section.

And in code we can `__attribute((used,section("segmentname,sectionname")))` to declare a var or function.

But how to declare an empty section in code?

Answer (score 2):

You already discovered the `section(...)` attribute, but no matter what you apply it to (even `struct {}` and `char[0]`), it's gonna take up some space and create a non-empty segment.

It seems there is no way to do *exactly* what you're asking from actual C code, but you can achieve a workaround by using inline assembly.

Include this code block somewhere outside of a function:

```
asm(".section __RESTRICT,__restrict\n"
    "empty:\n"
    ".no_dead_strip empty\n");
```

This will:

- add a truly empty (filesize: 0) segment/section to your object file.
- add an `empty` symbol to your symbol table, but:

  - it's gonna be private (i.e. non-linkable).
  - as long as it doesn't start with an underscore, the chances of it colliding with anything else are virtually zero.
- work in all of i386, x86_64, arm and arm64 assembly.